# Index of orthogonal projections

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory

I'm reading a paper 'The index of a Pair of Projections' by Avron, Seiler and Simon at the moment and have a question about a definition:

[image: Definition of Fredholm Pair]

What do they mean by $C$ viewed as a map from $\text{Ran }P$ to $\text{Ran }Q$? At first I thoght they probably just just mean $$C:\text{Ran }P\to\text{Ran } Q, \quad x\mapsto QPx.$$
But then a few lines later in the proof of Proposition 3.1 they write:

[image: Proof of Prop 3.1]

From which it seems they rather meant $$C:\text{Ran }P\to\text{Ran } Q, \quad x\mapsto Qx.$$

Or at least I don't see why $$\{\phi\in\text{Ran }P~|~QP\phi=0\}=\{\phi\in\text{Ran }P~|~Q\phi=0\}.$$

**Additional Question:**

Is there an easy way to see that $C$ is Fredholm if $P-Q$ is compact?

**Yes!**

By equality 3.2a/b and since $1\pm K$ has finite dimensional kernel for $K$ compact.

Answer (score 1):

If $x \in {\rm ran}\, P$, say $x = Py$, then, as $P$ is a projection $Px = P^2y = Px = x$, hence on ${\rm ran}\, P$ we have $QP = Q$.

Comment: Of course. Stupid me!